# How we can assign dashboard menus as per user role?

Tags: wordpress

Basically i have created WordPress project, in that i have uses caldera form, ultimate table, smart slider and Envira Gallery etc plugins to allow admin to updation to their website as he needed, but i want to create three admin for it very first, for him i can give permission to only create and posting post and viewing it's own post and modifying. and for second and third users i need to give permission to access all above installed plugins but not allow to give access to other dashboard menus like installing new plugins or creating new pages, i need to give access to that two users for only above mentioned plugin.

in that  i have used WP admin UI customize plugin but the problem is that for first user on dashboard it is showing unnecessarily wp-backrey menu, please suggest me how can i remove this menu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/.

It will do what, exactly you want.